# Creating Dot Density Maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, density

Is there a 'friendly' way to create dot-density maps, where a polygon attribute data defines the number of dots (e.g. 1 dot = 100 ) using QGIS 1.7+? I say friendly because after a couple of hours researching all the alternatives seem to require programming. Maybe I am not looking in the right place. I am already aware of the fTools 'Random Points' feature and it is not what I am looking for.

[image]

---

That is precisely what I am seeking. However every time I attempted to run this function. I received the following:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doRandPoints.py", line 118, in accept
self.randomize(inLayer, outPath, minimum, design, value)
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doRandPoints.py", line 210, in randomize
else: points = self.loopThruPolygons(inLayer, value, design)
File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doRandPoints.py", line 256, in loopThruPolygons
sExt = sGeom.boundingBox()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'

Python version:
2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:37:12) 
[GCC 4.5.2]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Trunk Trunk, exported
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what the output should look like and why fTools does not work for you?

Comment: Sure and thank you for following up! I am seeking to take an attribute like the number of children in a U.S. Census Tract. Instead of displaying the polygons as a Graduated Symbol, I would like to display 1 dot = 100 children. Effective I am seeking to replicate this: [link](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/GIS/Image/Dot%20Density%20Map_clip_image004.jpg)

Comment: Is your fTools updated? Have you checked with another polygon file? Maybe it's corrupted.

Comment: Hi you were correct. It appears my real data is being converted into strings. I am using LibreCalc and the data columns appear to not retain the attributes I specified. What is your approach to this problem?

Comment: What do you use Calc for? Consider using Field Calculator instead. You won't have troubles with data types then.

Comment: that is precisely how I overcame my issue. however is there documentation, tips for dbf csv file for export using libre calc? everything is for excel

Comment: dbf or csv? If you use csv you need a csvt file describing the data types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this result created using "Random points" is not what you are looking for, you'll have to be more specific about your requirements.

[image]

Comment: FWIW - in the newer version of QGIS 2.16.x this is now under the processing menu. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-qgis-2-16/202228#202228