# Points in Polygon missing from QGIS 2.16.x?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2.16, hexagonal-grid, hexagon-binning

Looking to do a basic Hex analyis with some random points within the Gulf of Mexico.

[image]

I created a hex grid from MMQGIS

Under my Vector tool - Analysis tools, I dont have Points in Polygon.

Is it missing on 2.16.3 (2.16.x)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in the Processing > Toolbox > search for Count Points in Polygon

Not sure why it's missing from the Vector menu...

Comment: Check this post for an explanation, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-qgis-2-16/202228#202228

Comment: Excellent,  Exactly what i needed.  Still new to QGis,  appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @JustinH glad to help... I have mixed feelings about that new implementation of the toolsets... but...

Comment: Point in polygons missing in the vector menu is a bug. I reported it in here: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15670. Will be fixed soon.