# Counting points in polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, count

I want to count points (1000 of students home) in district polygons with Qgis 2.16. I didn't find the tool in the analysis tools plugin.

Is there another plugin or method I could use to perform this task?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Try this [Points in polygon](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html), there is a tutorial for you If you have trouble finding the tool, check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212523/points-in-polygon-missing-from-qgis-2-16-x

Answer (score 20):

The tool you're looking for is now called ["Count points in polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#count-points-in-polygon), and it can be found in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) under `Vector analysis` tools or can be also launched found in `Vector > Analysis Tools > Count Points in Polygons`.

[image]