# Point in Polygon QGIS 2.18

Tags: point-in-polygon, qgis-2.18

Point in polygon does not appear in my QGIS 2.18.0 (Windows 10).

The tutorials indicate I should find it in Vector -> Analisis Tools -> Point in Polygons, but it is not there.

How should I install it?

Comment: Do you want to find the polygon which the point is inside? Then use overlay from processing toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for the answer: [How to count points in polygons with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213186/how-to-count-points-in-polygons-with-qgis?rq=1)
Im not happy with it, but 'they' have desided to cut it from analyse tools