# Finding neighbors of latitude longitude pair location

Tags: distance, indexing

I have a list of points (more than a few million) defined by latitude and longitude.
I want to find out the neighbors of each point.
For example, I want to know for each point, what the nearest point, or what the nearest 4 points? or how many neighbors are within 10km radius?

I want to do it programmatically, please provide some possible solutions.

So far I have used a for loop to find out the nearest neighbor:

```
//C++ example
for (i=0;i<npoint;i++)
  {
     lat1=latitude[i];
     lon1=longotide[i];
     for(j=0;j<npoint;j++)
        {
            lat2=latitude[j];
            lon2=longotide[j];
            distance = some_function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
            vDistance.push_back(distance);
         }
      //now we can find the smallest distance from the container
  }
```

But this only works for a limited data size.

Comment: In QGIS use menu vector : analyses : nearest neighbour to find the nearest neighbours of each point. See also [find nearest feature][1].

To find the number of neigbours within 10 km add a 10km-buffer to your points-layer. Then use menu vector : analyses : count points in polygon - see also [How to count points in polygons with QGIS?][2] Works similar in QGIS 3.x


  [1]: https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/wiki/Find_nearest_features
  [2]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213186/how-to-count-points-in-polygons-with-qgis

Comment: scipy's kdtree is helpful for this kind of analysis, but keep in mind that you would need to project your lat/long into some kind of coordinate system with non-degree units.

Comment: @jon, the problem is I have million to billion of points all over the globe. The points are distributed on a sphere.

Comment: I highly recommend doing this in [postgis](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor)

Comment: What have you a [tried to do so far](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange)? The question above as stated is [too broad](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @om_henners, Currently I have used a for loop to calculate the distance between points to solve the problem. But it was time consuming.

Comment: @Chang this is exactly what kdtree is built for--million to billion points.

Comment: I found this might help: https://gist.github.com/alexcpn/1f187f2114976e748f4d3ad38dea17e8