# Extracting coordinates of points from grid cells

Tags: qgis

Within QGIS, I have two layers: (1) a layer of points and (2) a grid layer. Each grid cell has its own ID.

For each grid cell with greater than 10 points, I'd like to extract the coordinates for the points. At the moment, there is no common variable between the grid layer and the points to do so.

Is there a simple way to do this with the processing toolbox?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213186/counting-points-in-polygons-using-qgis then select only the polygons with a count of 10 or more, clip the points and generate the coordinates https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-adding-x-y-coordinate - is this something like what you have tried already?