# QGIS 2.18.0 - missing Geometry tools in the Vector tab

Tags: qgis

Yesterday, the only vector processing tool I had was **Open Street Map**. After checking here, I re-installed QGIS and I had all the processing tools.

This morning, I have been using **Geometry tools**. When I deleted the layer I had created using **Export/Add geometry columns**, several processing tools, including **Geometry tools**, had disappeared.

I closed down QGIS and re-opened it and they were all back again.

Has anyone any idea what is going on please. It is annoying to have to close down and restart to be able to use a particular tool.

Comment: related: [Missing Processing Tools in Vector Menu of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

Some tools disappear when you reinstall QGIS. It's a bug, you can check it here: [Built-in tools missing from Vector menu](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15265). I got the same problem, deleting .qgis2 folder I solved this issue.

Try to do the same, but be careful, python plug-ins are in the same folder. If you don't want to lose them, make a backup and restore them in new .qgis2 folder (will be created after QGIS start).

Comment: I had read that thanks @aldo_tapia, but I could not follow it. Where will I find the .qgis2 folder please? In the Program files>QGIS 2,18 > Apps, I have a qgis folder, but no .qgis2 folder.

Comment: On Windows, it is under `C:\Users\<YourUsername>`.