# Incomplete geometry tool in QGIS 2.18 'Las Palmas'

Tags: qgis, vector, convert

[image]

I just installed new version of QGIS which is 2.18 'Las Palmas'. Unfortunately, I cannot find vector conversion menu under geometry tool that I used to find in the previous version. I need to convert poly line to point, and polyline to polygon.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Andi! Check the **Processing Toolbox**, the tools should be available there. You should also delete the _processing_ folder in your `/.qgis2/python/plugins` directory if it exists (this was used in older versions of QGIS but is no longer needed).

Comment: This post is also highly relevant: [Missing Processing Tools in Vector Menu - QGIS 2.16](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-qgis-2-16)