# "Data management tools" does not exist under "Vector layer"?

Tags: qgis, tools

I am using QGIS 2.18.12 and I need to calculate the area of overlap between two shapefiles. Help I've already found for this problem says to use "Data management tools" under "Vector layer" but the former does not exist in my version of QGIS.

Can someone explain what I need to do?

Comment: Thanks Luke, fTools doesn't even show up when I search for it in available plugins

Comment: This worked! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis