# Missing Conversion | Rasterise option in raster menu

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm using QGIS.
Would like to use Raster > Conversion > Rasterise from drop down menu.
Raster drop down menu is smaller today than it was yesterday though... why?

How can I access the missing options?

Note, I'm aware rasterisation can be done through processing toolbox, but I don't want to use that for various reasons.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Maybe you killed python support? You can click on the rightmost symbol in the status bar to see error messages from startup.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: Original poster here. I got this sorted out by enabling GDALtools plugin - though it is not obvious that the error is fixed straight away. For the record, I was using v.2.18.14 on Windows 10.

Comment: Nice that it's fixed. Can you vote for my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3** : You need to enable the `Processing` plugin. (both raster and vector)

**QGIS 2** : You need to enable the `GdalTools` plugin in your plugin manager.
[image]

After that, the Raster menu will come back with more algorithms.

Comment: How? My plugin menu looks just like yours; options are faded out so I cannot select them.

Comment: I can check/uncheck the checkbox next to 'GdalTools'. If I don't enable it, my raster menu is nearly empty, only the raster calculator and align raster are there. If I check it, then all my rasters algorithms come back in the menu. Which items do you have in your raster menu?

Comment: i use this technique - i find that sometimes if I disable/uninstall a lot of plugins at one time, gdaltools turns itself off (or I do it by mistake)

Comment: "GDAL tools" has been renamed "Processing"

Answer (score 1):

See a similar issue with the vector menu here, [Missing Processing Tools in Vector Menu of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis).  This was a known issue for version 2.16, that according to the qgis.org [bug tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15265) they were shipping updates to the processing toolboxes via the plugin manager.  This is likely the source of the issue for your changing raster processing toolbox as well; go into your user folder and check the .qgis2 folder (should be in a location like:  C:\users\yourusername\.qgis2\python\plugins) - if there is a Processing folder in there, then an update is likely the source of the issue.  As these tools are core functionality in QGIS, you can safely delete that and it should correct the problem upon reloading QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

In the 3.8.1, I have been able to enable missing items with enabling "Processing" from plugins.