# Missing Processing Tools in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis-processing, python-2.7

The processing tools is missed in QGIS 2.18. I tried [Missing Processing Tools in Vector Menu of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/202111/113692)  solutions, even install and uninstall several times but every time I get the following error (Images). The problem started when I tried to install pip and openpyxl. I installed these libraries in the C:\windows path (as administrator). after that, the processing tools disappeared.

I installed qgis 3.0 through osgeo4w and the processing appears. but I need the stable version.

```
Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy. Original error was: DLL load failed: %1 ist keine zul�ssige Win32-Anwendung. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 55, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 110, in 
    from .RasterLayerStatistics import RasterLayerStatistics
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterLayerStatistics.py", line 36, in 
    from processing.tools import raster
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\raster.py", line 29, in 
    import numpy
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in 
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: %1 ist keine zul�ssige Win32-Anwendung.



Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.17 Las Palmas, 98e769f70e 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/AmirS/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/AmirS/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~2/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~2\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~2\bin
C:\Users\AmirS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/AmirS/.qgis2//python
```

[image: After Installation]
[image: Erorr]
[image]

Comment: What are the "above solutions" that you have tried?  Please present all errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by deleting every single python file, package and program from my computer. I did the same with QGIS. They were hidden everywhere. After reinstalling QGIS everything is ok.

The pip package which I was looking for, was in AppData directory.