# Why vector tools cannot appear in QGIS data processing

Tags: qgis-processing

Why vector tools cannot appear in QGIS data processing
[image]

Comment: this questions deals with something similar, it might be of help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis

Comment: Hi dickysetiawan, Generally, the absence of items in the _Vector_ menu denotes a problem with the _Processing_ plugin. Can you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/352689/edit) your question post to include screenshots of the _Help ~> About_ and the _Plugins ~> Manage and Install Plugins ~> Installed_ windows?

Comment: I am not sure which version you are using, it happened to me once, just close QGIS and reopen it. If not, I suggest you install the latest version or re-install QGIS in an extreme case.